# Зачем нужны темы в yii?

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, зачем нужны темы и когда лучше их использовать? Почему бы не пользоваться просто представлением для разделения статических частей страницы (шапка, футер)? Не совсем понимаю...

И еще, можно ли задавать несколько тем? Допустим для самого сайта, а потом для админской панели? Как реализуется смена темы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Подскажите, зачем нужны темы и когда лучше их использовать?

Для того же, для чего и в вордпрессе: для предоставления возможности разного дизайна одного и того же приложения без необходимости переписывать файлы. Также темы костыльно реализуют наследственность шаблонов: при задании шаблонов в дефолтной папке приложения их можно переопределить шаблонами в папке темы, и, таким образом, отобразить измененное представление в дефолтном лейауте и наоборот.

> Почему бы не пользоваться просто представлением для разделения статических частей страницы (шапка, футер)?

Потому что в Yii сделан выбор в пользу общего шаблона (лейаута) и виджетов. Произвольные места в шаблоне все равно упираются в необходимость виджетов, и статические части просто становятся лишним грузом - их проще оформить в виде виджетов и не тратить время на поддержку ненужной сущности. Не говоря уж о том, что в серьезном приложении всегда находятся какие-нибудь промо-страницы, где все перевернуто с ног на голову, и тут проще уже написать отдельный лейаут. Ну и никто не мешает отдельные файлы в лейауте подключать.

> И еще, можно ли задавать несколько тем?

Одновременно - нет, задавать произвольную тему при запросе - пожалуйста:

```
Yii::app()->theme = 'default'; // используется тема default.
```

Но, в общем, в этом нет большого смысла, этот функционал требуется крайне редко.

> Допустим для самого сайта, а потом для админской панели?

Можно, но я бы не стал так делать. Вам надо задавать тему либо в конфиге, либо в рантайме, и это может быть просто лишней информацией. С другой стороны, если у вас разные конфиги для админки и фронтэнда, то почему бы и не развязать визуальные представления.

Comment: Yii::app()->theme->name = 'default';  


Проверяли? Так работает? Мне был известен только

    Yii::app()->setTheme('default');

Comment: @dekameron, я наврал, конечно, сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 3):

Можно задавать сколько угодно тем.
При использовании темы ее надо указать в конфиге:

```
return array(
    'name' => 'SiteName',
    'theme' => 'themeDirectory' //Чувствительна к регистру в Unix-based системах
    //...
);
```

Использовать можно на свое усмотрение, и сколько угодно (Например разрешить авторизированным пользователям выбирать тему самим, а неавторизированным писать ее же в куки)

Вот небольшой [Guide](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.theming) по темам